# Is it possible to tile windows more than just left and right?

Tags: release-odin, gala, odin, window-manager

I am giving elementary a new try and I cannot find a setting for tiling windows to the corners (splitting the left or right tile), not even to upper and bottom half of the screen (thus split the screen up/down).

Just right and left tile are present in settings:

[image]

There are some options in `dconf` / `gsettings` present, but they are not followed:

[image]

That list in dconf looks odd. Dconf reflects some keybindings for windows set in System Settings > Keyboard > Windows (e.g. for minimize) but doesn't reflect others.

This is so trivial in other desktops, is it really absent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it really is absent.

There is an issue for it on GitHub here: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/105

If you have anything to add to the discussion, do that there. Give the original post there a ️ to show that you want this too.